# How to append formData as a Array Object to server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-data

I'm new for Form Data.
I would like to know how can I append array object into formData and send to server (without any parse or transform needed)

I have a data set as below:

```
var arrObj = [
  {arr: [1, 2, 3], name: 'name1', id: 'id1'},
  {arr: [6, 7], name: 'name2', id: 'id2'},
]
```

I'm not sure is it posible to get the result such as below in the server?

```
{
  arrObj[]: [
    {arr[]:[1,2,3], name: 'name1', id:'id1'}, 
    {arr[]:[6, 7], name: 'name2', id:'id2'}
  ]
}
```

I did some research, I know I can use JSON.stringify and parse it on server, but I'm looking for an alternative way.

I've tried to append Array into form data, and it works. But I have no idea do I able to add in the object as value.

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   formData.append('charater[]', arr[i]);
}
```

The code above works for Array. In server, I will get this result `{ charater[]: ['a', 'b', 'c'] }`

Is it possible to get the result I want (or maybe similiar)? If no, how can I handle the array object in the client side and the server?

Comment: What's wrong with JSON?

Comment: Use JSON, it's the correct way of doing things. Don't get yourself into unnecessary trouble

Comment: Nothing wrong, just wish to know more what form data can be achieved.

Comment: That will probably depend on your back-end. For instance I think for php, you could retrieve something like `fd.append('arrObj[0][arr][]', 1); fd.append('arrObj[0][arr][]', 2); fd.append('arrObj[0][arr][]', 3); fd.append('arrObj[0][name], "name1");`. But really, there is absolutely no good reasons to do that. Just send your data as a JSON string `fd.append( 'data', JSON.stringify(data))`. Your back-end certainly has built-ins to parse it to its own object model.